# Join two tables and group by two columns

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables.

**User Table**

```
id | country
```

**Post Table**

```
id | userId | type
```

in the Post table I have 3 types of posts.

```
'Social', 'Economic', 'Culture'
```

I need to group the data in order to obtain the count of posts per type.

eg.

```
country | social  | economic | culture
UK      | 2       | 1        | 0       
US      | 0       | 2        | 1       
LK      | 1       | 0        | 0       
IN      | 0       | 0        | 3
```

I wrote the following query which seems to group the data only using the country. How can I port this such that it counts the `type` of post?

```
SELECT b.country, SUM(a.type) 
FROM Post a 
INNER JOIN User b ON a.id = b.id 
GROUP BY b.country, a.type
```

Can anyone give me pointer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.country, 
       SUM(a.type = 'Social') as social,
       SUM(a.type = 'Economic') as economic,
       SUM(a.type = 'Culture') as culture
FROM Post a 
INNER JOIN User b ON a.id = b.id 
GROUP BY b.country
```

The `sum()` adds up how many time the condition is `true`.
Only group by data you want to have its own row in the result set.